# Optimization of convex integral function

Tags: definite-integrals, convex-optimization

I have the following constrained optimization with the integral objective function
$$
\min_{x_i\in D} \int_{t_1}^{t_2} \frac 1 {t - \sum\limits_{i = 1}^N x_i f_i (t)} \, dt 
$$
where $t - \sum\limits_{i = 1}^N x_i f_i(t) > 0 $ and $f_i(t)$ are polynomial functions. $D$ is a convex set. How can I solve the optimization problem?

Comment: What do you mean by twice $dt$?

Comment: I corrected it.

Comment: Please check. I think there are many more typos. Example: check the integration limit. Also, could you please tell me over which variable you want to minimize? (Actually, I am not able to figure it out.)

Comment: The minimization is over $x_i$.

Answer (score 0):

Do not know whether it will work or not, but you can try this way-

**Step-$1$:**
$$\frac{d}{dx_i}\int_{t_1}^{t_2}g(x_i,t)dt=\int_{t_1}^{t_2}\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}g(x_i,t)dt+\frac{dt_2}{dx_i}\times g(x_i,t_2)-\frac{dt_1}{dx_i} \times g(x_i,t_1).$$

**Step-$2$:**
At $x_i =x_i^*$, the derivative will be zero.

**Step-$3.a$:**
Project $x_i^*$ on $D$ if $x_i^* \notin D$. You will find a unique point because $D$ is a convex set (but also the closeness of the set is required).

**Step-$3.b$:**
No need to do anything further, if $x_i^* \in D$. $x_i^*$ is the answer.

Comment: Thank you. Actually, it is not easy to calculate the integral and it's derivative without knowing x!